# With the new Apple Music app is there a way to sort my music by Album?

Tags: music.app, sort, album

It seems that Apple have messed up sorting again in the new Apple Music app. I want to sort my music by Album Title, not by Artist and then Title. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  I had the same problem.

Go to Settings → Music → Sort Albums and change this to By Title.